# Ubercart checkout using a manual html form

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, ubercart

I'm basically creating my own interface for choosing among different product options, in Drupal 7, using Ubercart.
I want to manually create an html form where I will be submitting post variables which represent the details of the product(s).

Is this something possible to do? Is there any documentation on this? I hope it's simple enough.

Comment: I hope my question is clear. Once the user submits the form, it will take him to the checkout page, with the cart populated with the submitted post variables

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a custom module ( lets call it mymodule )
2. register a valid url where your html form can be accessed use [hook_menu](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7)

   ```
   $items['mymodule/submit'] = array(
     'page callback' => 'mymodule_submit', 
     'access arguments' => array('access content'), 
     'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
   );
   ```
3. Now create the function mymodule_submit() in your module and use $_POST variable to check for values and act accordingly.